# How to make Activities of my Library module private

Tags: android, android-activity, private

I have created a library module in Android Studio and included it in a new project. I can access all the Activities of my library in my app project. But I want to hide all Activities and expose only some classes of the library to any project that includes it. 
How can I do that?

Comment: How do you implement your library? Is it a published library or just local module you're integrating?

Comment: My first thought would be do create another module that your library uses, so your library uses the activities in other module, but exposes on this that actually are present in the library ?

Comment: You can use https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#restrict annotation for that purpose, but doesn't work for local module integration.

Comment: @JeelVankhede atm it is local library. But i plan to publish it later.